# Verilog. How Can I Set Delays in An Always Block While Waiting for Inputs?

Tags: verilog

I've come across a problem recently while working on my assignment about a single cycle CPU in verilog. I would like to ask a few questions:

There are 3 verilog file, which are cpu.v, **instruction_memory_v**, and data_memory_v.

the CPU will first send the address of the first instruction(which is o_i_addr_wire) to the instruction memory, then **AFTER 5 CLOCK CYCLES**, the instruction memory will send the corresponding instruction (which is i_i_inst, here I assign it to i_i_inst_reg) back to the CPU, which I can proceed to decode and execute it. I have to process all the instruction until the instruction 0xEEEEEEEE is encountered, and set the register **o_finish_wire** to 1 to terminate the program.

I've been trying to figure out how to deal with this but in vain. I've tried the following method.
All of the following data types are reg.

```
    always @(posedge i_clk or negedge i_rst_n) begin
        o_i_valid_addr_wire = 1;           // inform the instruction memory
        o_i_addr_wire = ins_next_addr;     // the address was initially 0
        ins_next_addr = ins_next_addr + 4; // increment to program counter 

        // trying to set delay by 5 clock cycles, until the instruction is ready after 25 ns
        repeat(25) @(posedge i_clk);

        // the program wouldn't terminate here
        if (i_i_inst_reg == 32'b11111111111111111111111111111111) o_finish_wire = 1;

        // decode and execute......
        rs1        = i_i_inst_reg[19:15];
        rs2        = i_i_inst_reg[24:20];
        write_reg  = i_i_inst_reg[11:7];
        read_data1 = register[rs1];
        read_data2 = register[rs2];
        imm_val    = i_i_inst_reg[31:20];
        funct3     = i_i_inst_reg[14:12];
        opcode     = i_i_inst_reg[6:0];
```

But this does not seem to work. Not even the first instruction was correct.

I would like to know if I'm missing out on something, or what are the better approaches.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not synthesizable. Is this what you want?

Comment: As above - is this meant only to work in simulation? If no, can use ` repeat(25) @(posedge i_clk);`  Generally have you simulated it at all? If so can you expand on whats not working? Searching for verilog state machines might show good examples of counting off cycles like you need...